# As a USA citizen/resident, can I apply for a Chinese visa while in a foreign country?

Tags: visas, china, us-citizens, istanbul

I'm a USA citizen/resident traveling the world through multiple countries and interested in visiting where a friend of mine lives.

Can I apply for a visa from a Chinese embassy/consulate in one of the countries I'm visiting (e.g. I'm in Istanbul next week). Or do I have to return to the USA to apply for the visa?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you cannot apply for a Chinese visa from a country of which you are not a citizen or permanent resident.

Specifically for [Turkey](http://tr.chineseembassy.org/eng/lsfw/t1140055.htm) (my emphasis):

> (3) Proof of legal stay or residence status(applicable to those not
>   applying for the visa in their country of citizenship)
>
> If you are not applying for the visa in the country of your
>   citizenship, you must provide the original and photocopy of your valid
>   certificates or **visa of stay, residence, employment or student status**,
>   or other valid certificates of legal staying provided by the relevant
>   authorities of the country where you are currently staying.

You'll note visitor is not a valid status. This means that you'll have to apply in advance for your visa from the US.

*Although the link in my answer is to `chineseembassy.org`, apparently this is the official domain for foreign missions as per the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs' website](http://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/wjb_663304/zwjg_665342/2490_665344/2492_665348/t14409.shtml).*

Comment: This actually varies from country to country, as the definition of "legal proof of stay" is different in each embassy location.  In some countries you only need to have a tourist visa and hotel verification, in other countries you need a long stay or work type visa.  The OP needs to check with the Chinese Embassy in each country he visits to see if it is possible there.